# How to add mathematical calculations in Django?

Tags: html, python-3.x, postgresql, django-3.0

I am totally confused how to add math calculations in django to display on my page? I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. Thank you for your help :D

comment:

I am familiar with django, I have already made one app for myself in Django as well as in Flask, but that was to fill in tables on a page and write to a database, and now I want to make a program for sports plane calculations and I am stuck.... I don't know how to work with mathematical and physical data

I need practical tips on how to do this, not links to Djang's tutorial, although I am grateful for those too :D

calculate.py

```
from random import randint
import time
t = time.time()

class Calc:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def position(self):

        self.positionX = []
        self.positionY = []

        self.positionX.append([(randint(1, 100) * x) for x in range(1, 2, 1)])
        self.positionY.append([(randint(1, 100) * y) for y in range(1, 2, 1)])

        return self.positionX, self.positionY


    def __str__(self):
        return {self.positionX, self.positionY}

if __name__ == '__main__':

        t = 0
        while t < 20:
            hear = Calc()
            print('X: ', hear.position()[0], 'Y: ', hear.position()[1])
            time.sleep(0.4)
            t += 1
```

models.py

```
class CleanRobot(models.Model):
    """Robot Position and Speed Simulator"""
    name = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOOSE)
    velocity = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    positionX = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    positionY = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    angleTHETA = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "CleanRobot"
        verbose_name_plural = "CleanRobots"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py
# @method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CleanRobotView(View):
'''... '''

```
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, Calc())
```

forms.py

```
class Robo(forms.ModelForm):
    """New note add form"""

    class Meta:
        model = CleanRobot
        fields = '__all__'

html
{% block title %}Robot{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ positionX }}

{#        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-second btn-lg" value="Wyślij">#}
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a href="{% url 'menu' %}">Powrót</a></button>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ok. You should do the tutorial that is explained at the django site so you will have a first impression how Django works. Django can be complex at the begining due to the defined file structures. For this kind of Application i would recommend Flask since it is easy to understand and very light. FLASK: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/ DJANGO TUTORIAL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I'm familiar with django, I've already made myself one app in Django as well as in Flask, but that was to populate tables on a page and write to a database, and now I want to make a program to calculate a sports plane and I'm stuck.... I don't know how to work with mathematical and physical data....